# Kubernetes Helm Chart Template if-condition

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

In my helm template I want to have the following block:

```
ports:
  - containerPort: {{ .Values.ports.containerPort | default 8080}}
    name: {{ .Values.ports.name | default "8080tcp02" | quote}}
    protocol: {{ .Values.ports.protocol | default "TCP" | quote}}
          {{- end }}
```

If in `values.yaml` file block `ports` exist, then take values for `containerPort`, `name` and`protocol` from there. Otherwise, if block `ports` is absent in `values.yaml`, then take default values. Now I'm getting `nil pointer evaluating interface {}.containerPort`, if block `ports` is absent in `values.yaml`.

I also tried to do so:

```
{{- with .Values.ports }}
ports:
  - containerPort: {{ .containerPort | default 8080}}
    name: {{ .name | default "8080tcp02"}}
    protocol: {{ .protocol | default "TCP"}}
{{- end }}
```

But then If block `ports` is absent in `values.yaml` It will absent in result as well. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
  ports:
    {{- if .Values.ports }}
    {{- with . }}
    - containerPort: {{ .containerPort }}
      name: {{ .name |  quote }}
      protocol: {{ .protocol | quote }}
    {{- else }}
    - containerPort: 8080
      name: 8080tcp02
      protocol: TCP
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
```

Now it works with if statement, but not with `with` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try if/else block:

```
ports:
 {{- if .Values.ports }}
  - containerPort: {{ .Values.ports.containerPort | default 8080 }}
    name: {{ .Values.ports.name | default "8080tcp02" }}
    protocol: {{ .Values.ports.protocol | default "TCP" }}
 {{- else }}
  - containerPort: 8080
    name: "8080tcp02"
    protocol: "TCP"
 {{- end }}
```

Loop thru the ports:

```
 ports:
 {{- if .Values.ports }}
 {{- range $content := .Values.ports }}
  - containerPort: {{ $content.containerPort | default 8080 }}
    name: {{ $content.name | default "8080tcp02" }}
    protocol: {{ $content.protocol | default "TCP" }}
 {{- end }}
 {{- else }}
  - containerPort: 8080
    name: "8080tcp02"
    protocol: "TCP"
 {{- end }}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Can I also somehow acheive not to write the whole path to each variable like `.Values.ports.containerPort `, but `{{ .containerPort }}` in if statement?

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work, perhaps I am using `with` not properly.. (I have edited the question with example) In case I have block `ports` in `values.yaml` It says `missing required field "containerPort"`.

Comment: Checkout the updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, don't see update with `with` in the answer. Must it be there?

Comment: Use `range` here because the ports is a list.